# How do I use jdk.net.hosts.file and fallback to default NS resolution?

Tags: java, hosts

After I added `-Djdk.net.hosts.file` property my app cannot resolve the name of my local machine. Is there a way to make it fallback to default resolution when nothing found in the hosts file I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Java sources it seems that there is no fallback, i.e. it's either the file based name resolution or the system's.

Comment: Worth noting that according to [JEP 418](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/418): "An application can use the non-standard, JDK-specific system property jdk.net.hosts.file [...] This feature is useful for testing but it is not a general purpose solution since the complete list of host names is not always known in advance."